# Lightbox compatibilty issue for IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, lightbox, compatibility

I am using Lightbox form this website: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ and it works fine for chrome, firefox, safari, and opera. But when I tried in IE, the lightbox doesn't work. I have tried to open the lightbox website on IE and it works, I have followed the instructions as well. But when it comes to my own website it doesn't work. Can someone explain why and how to solve the issue? Do i need certain additional code to make it compatible?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank You

IE9 / 1.11.0

**Related HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<div class="work">
    <a href="images/img1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data title="Chrysanthemum">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" border=0></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.work {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0;
}
.work img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -32.8% 0 0 -50%;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you post what you've done? Hard to help without seeing the work

Comment: IE 9  

HTML:                                                            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>                  <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

<div class="work">
<a href="images/img1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data title="Chrysanthemum"><img src="images/img1.jpg" border=0></a>
</div>

CSS:
.work {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 0;
}

.work img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative; 
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -32.8% 0 0 -50%;
}

@Ben Do you need more code to be revealed? Thank You

Comment: I setup a JSFiddle and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/8nKA8/4/

That said - if you google: ie9 lightbox - it returns alot of forum posts on similar issues... If you aren't already, ensure you are using the latest version of lightbox, and that your IE is NOT in compatibility mode